# Query Distinct Column Names with Highest 2nd Column

Tags: sql

My title may be trash so feel free to word it better, but this is what I am trying to write a query for the below data

```
letter   number
  A        2
  A        1
  A        7
  B        3
  B        9
  C        1 
  C        1
  C        0
  C        7
  C        5
  D        8
  D        8
  D        4
  E        2
```

I want it to display the distinct letters along with the highest number for each letter. So something like this:

```
A   7
B   9
C   7
D   8
E   2
```

I have the base of it down I think but just can't seem to get only 1 result for each letter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT letter, number from "Table name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following SQL:

```
select letter,
       max(number) as max_number
  from your_table
 group by letter
 order by letter;
```